# How do I tell what is running on which ports in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, port

How could I tell what is listening on which ports on Ubuntu?  In other words, how do I get a list of ports that are in use?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

"In use" as in with an active connection, or that programs are listening on? Or both?

Run `sudo netstat -lp` in your terminal; this will tell you what ports are open to receive connections, and what programs are listening on them. Try `sudo netstat -p` for the same thing, *plus* currently-active connections.

Comment: I think both is best ;)

Comment: What was a little strange is that I have tomcat and apache servers running and neither port 8080 nor 80 showed up in the list.  Would you know why that would happen?

Comment: @Genadinik Verify what port they are configured to listen on; for Apache this is the Listen directive in its config file, but I don't know about Tomcat.

Comment: `fuser -n tcp 8080` will approach it from the other end; showing you which process (if any) is listening on TCP port 8080.

Comment: If what Kromey suggested didn't cut it, try `sudo netstat -tulpn`.

Comment: use `ss` now https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025568/has-netstat-been-replaced-with-a-new-tool